# Changing the color of the parent component based upon the selection in the child component

Tags: angular

I have a child component which is having a dropdrown of colors.Based upon what is selected in the dropdown list, the colour of the parent component should change.

As of now I am able to successfully change the color of the child component based upon the color selection ,but i want to change the color of the parent component.
Any help?
I am also able to print the Value of the dropdown in the parent component as I am using a reference variable but I want the color to change as well.

header.component.html:

```
import { Component, OnInit,Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {


  styles: string[] = [];
  selectedStyle: string;


  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit(){

    this.styles = ['red','green','blue','none'];
    }

}
```

header.component.html

```
<div [ngClass]="selectedStyle" >

    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedStyle">
       <option *ngFor="let s of styles" [ngValue]="s">{{s}}</option>
    </select>

    </div>
```

app.component.html

```
<div [ngClass]="child.selectedStyle"><app-header #child></app-header></div>
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>
  <h1>{{child.selectedStyle}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle the select change event in your header component HTML.

header.component.html

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedStyle" (ngModelChange)="onStyleChange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let s of styles" [ngValue]="s">{{s}}</option>
</select>
```

Add an event handler for your select and an event emitter to your header component typescript.

header.component.ts

```
// trigger events using this
@Output() styleChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

// handle style change events using this
onStyleChange(style: string): void {
  // trigger event
  this.selectedStyle = style;
  this.styleChange.emit(style);
}
```

Handle the style change event in the parent HTML.

app.component.html

```
<app-header #child (styleChange)="onStyleChange($event)">
</app-header>
```

Handle the style change event in your parent typescript, and set a property that is available to your parent's HTML.

app.component.ts

```
style: string;

onStyleChange(style: string): void {
  this.style = style;
}
```

Whatever style is emitted from the child component is now available to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using @Output and emitting selected value 'up' to parent component.

```
<app-picker (select)="onPickerSelect($event)" [default]="defaultTheme"></app-picker>
```

Use @HostBinding to attach sanitized style to your component.

```
  @HostBinding('style') get style() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`background: ${this.selectedStyle.background}; color: ${this.selectedStyle.color}`);
  }
```

I would suggest you also use interface for style to avoid partial styling or cases when you forget to implement some styles.

```
interface Style {
  background: string;
  color: string;
}

const styles : {[ key : string ] : Style } = {
  red: {
    background: '#ff0000',
    color: '#ffffff'
  },
  blue: {
    background: '#0000ff',
    color: '#00ff00'
  }
}
```

Working stackblitz can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/bubble-up-style